# Is it possible to set Spyder auto-completion without pressing the tab key?

Tags: spyder

I'm using Spyder 2.3.4 (shipped with Anaconda) on Windows. The tab completion works fine. I'm wondering is it possible to do the auto-completion without pressing tab key each time?

(Sublime and Intellij could pop up auto-completion window when typing part of the function names.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) Unfortunately this is not possible with our current version (i.e. Spyder **3.2.3**). However, we are (most probably) going to implement this feature for our next major release (i.e. Spyder **4.0**).

Comment: Thank you! It's good get response from the Spyder dev. I hope the new version would release soon.